# How can I implement a TcP connection on my turtle based Pong game, to create a 2 player game?

Tags: python, tcp, turtle-graphics, pong

I'm trying to create a 2 person Pong game, that can be played by 2 different clients (possibly on 2 different machines) using a TCP connection (sockets). I have made my Pong with Turtle. I've also practised a bit with the server-client connections by sending messaged back and forth. The problem is that I can't seem to be able to implement this method in my game. I think I have too little knowledge of the socket-structure.

I have already tried to put my code into classes first, as that would make it easier to implement the socket connections, but that didn't really work out so I kept it easier for now. Also tried to make the code with pygame, but for some reason, that is bugged on my computer.

http://christianthompson.com/sites/default/files/Pong/pong.py
My code is based on this youtuber's code.

I expect/hope that this is a solvable problem and that you can help me move forward with this. I don't expect any fully written code or anything like that, just a nudge in the right direction, where to implement the sending/receiving, where to put the game code (client or server), what to look out for etc.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your question with [mre] *in the question itself*.

Comment: This is the easiest i could make my question, as it consists of multiple subparts